# EPSG Equidistant cylindrical

Tags: gdal

I need to know what is the epsg code for equidistant cylindrical because i have  to georeference an image Aquarius using gdal_translate

Answer (score 1):

How about [EPSG:4087](http://epsg.io/4087)? Otherwise one of this [list](http://epsg.io/?q=equidistant%20cylindrical)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @iant, there are several possibilities. I therefore suggest that you use the proj4 string with gdal, which you can customize based on your needs. e.g.

> "+proj=eqc +lat_ts=60 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84
>   +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"